# mongodb how to mongodump only indexes to another mongodb instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, tokumx

I have a mongodb instance with a lot of data, now I need to start up a new instance with the same structure without data.

how to get it done?

Answer (score 18):

You can do that with the "query" option, with a query that does not return any document. Something like:

```
mongodump -q '{ "foo" : "bar"  }'
```

This will dump all the dbs and indexes, you can then do a mongorestore to recreate them into another mongod instance

See documentation:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query

Comment: Good trick. However if you do have a big collection without "foo" indexed, it will be very slow. The workaround is using _id which always has index: mongodump -q '{ "_id" : "bar"  }'

Comment: Well may I raise this ironic - here we discuss about why mongnodb NOT restore index when mongorestore ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36977817/248616

Comment: As of version 3.6.3, this trick doesn't quite work. I get `bad option: cannot dump using a query without a specified collection`. It works if I specify the collection - but of course this means that I have to know all the collections before I start.

Answer (score 9):

You can login into mongo shell and execute the following code statements to generate creating indexes statements. After that, use the statements to recreate indexes.

```
var collectionList = db.getCollectionNames();
for(var index in collectionList){
    var collection = collectionList[index];
        var cur = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes();
        if(cur.length == 1){
            continue;
        }
        for(var index1 in cur){
            var next = cur[index1];
            if(next["name"] == '_id_'){
                continue;
            }
       var unique=next["unique"]?true:false;
       print("try{ db.getCollection(\""+collection+"\").createIndex("+JSON.stringify(next["key"])+",{unique:"+unique+"},{background:1})}catch(e){print(e)}");}}
```

Comment: If I could give you +1 ten extra times on this I would.  Nice little script.

Answer (score 6):

There is really short and briliant script for create backup of indexes queries:

```js
print(`// Backup indexes of : ${db.getName()} : database`);
print(`use ${db.getName()};`);

db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function (collection) {
    indexes = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes().forEach(function (index) {
        if (index.name === '_id_') return; // skip defalut _id indexes
        const keys = tojsononeline(index.key);
        delete index.id; delete index.key; delete index.v; delete index.ns;
        print(`db.${collection}.createIndex(${keys}, ${tojsononeline(index)});`);
    });
});
```

You can run it directly from mongo shell like this:

```sh
mongo --quiet mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase indexes-backup.js
```

Output looks like:

```js
db.user.createIndex({"user.email":1}, {"name":"userEmail", "background":true});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Ivan's answer, I improved the script by adding more options like `expireAfterSeconds` (*which was crucial for me*) and an flag variable to drop indexes before creating them. `dropFirst` variable at the top of the script can be set to `true` to drop every index before creating it. Also, this script keeps existing names of the indexes.

```js
var dropFirst = false;

for(var collection of db.getCollectionNames()) {
    var indexes = db.getCollection(collection).getIndexes().filter(i => i.name !== '_id_');
    if(indexes.length === 0) continue;
    print(`\n// Collection: ${collection}`);
    for(var index of indexes) {
        var key = JSON.stringify(index.key);
        var opts = [`name: "${index.name}"`, 'background: true'];
        if(index['unique']) opts.push('unique: true');
        if(index['hidden']) opts.push('hidden: true');
        if(index['sparse']) opts.push('sparse: true');
        if(index['expireAfterSeconds'] !== undefined) opts.push(`expireAfterSeconds: ${index['expireAfterSeconds']}`);
        if(dropFirst) {
            print(`try { db.getCollection("${collection}").dropIndex(${key}); } catch(e) { print('failed to drop ${key}:', e); }`);
        }
        print(`try { db.getCollection("${collection}").createIndex(${key}, {${opts.join(', ')}}) } catch(e) { print('failed to create ${key}:', e) }`);
    }
}
```